# Minimal polynomial of diagonalizable matrix

Tags: matrices, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

> Prove that a matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial's roots are all of algebraic multiplicity one.

Comment: Then bring $A$ to Jordan form and see what happens.

Comment: Oh right. So simple and I didn't even think about it.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2676557/173147

Answer (score 12):

Evaluating a polynomial$~P$ at a matrix commutes with change of basis: $C^{-1}P[A]C=P[C^{-1}AC]$ for any invertible matrix $C$. This means that the polynomials annihilating $A$ are the same as those annihilating $C^{-1}\!AC$, and in particular their minimal polynomials are the same. Now if $A$ is diagonalisable then there is some diagonal $D=C^{-1}\!AC$, and evaluation $P$ at $D$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries obtained by evaluating $P$ at the corresponding diagonal entry (eigenvalue) of$~D$. It follows that in this case the minimal polynomial of$~D$, and of$~A$, is a product of distinct factors $(X-a_i)$, one for each distinct eigenvalue$~a_i$; in particular it has simple roots.

Conversely if any product $P$ of distinct factors $(X-a_i)$ has $P[A]=0$ (in particular if the minimal polynomial of$~A$ has this form) then because all these factors are pairwise relatively prime the kernel decomposition theorem says
$$
  V=\ker(0)=\ker(P[A])=
  \ker(A-a_1I)\oplus\ker(A-a_2I)\oplus\cdots\oplus\ker(A-a_kI),
$$
and the nonzero factors on the right are the eigenspaces of $A$, showing that $A$ is diagonalisable.

Answer (score 4):

Without resorting to Jordan normal form, suppose

$A\sim $$
\left(\begin{matrix}
a_{11} &  0  & \ldots & 0\\
0  &  a_{22} & \ldots &0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0  &   0       &\ldots & a_{nn}
\end{matrix}\right)
$

We rewrite the set $\{a_{11},\ldots ,a_{nn}\}$ as $\{b_1,\ldots,b_d\}$ where the $b_i$ are **distinct** complex numbers.

Now consider the polynomial $\displaystyle P=\prod_{k=1}^d(X-b_k)$.

Prove (if needed) that $P$ annihilates $A$.

$P$ has simple roots and $A$'s minimal polynomial divides $P$.

Therefore $A$'s minimal polynomial's roots are all of algebraic multiplicity $1$.

Comment: This only shows the easy direction of the implication (diagonalisable implies minimal polynomial has simple roots).

Comment: Why does a diagonalizable matrix must have distinct eigen values? Take the unit matrix I, it has eigenvalue of 1 with algebraic multiplicity of n.

Comment: @YardenCohen I did not write that. $b_1,\ldots,b_d$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Oh true, my fault, I'm struggling understanding this theory and minimal polynomial in particular.  If I take [1,1;0,0] which has minimal polynomial of t(t-1) which the roots are distinct as needed but the matrix is not diagonalizable