# How to determine diagonability from Minimal polynomial.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials

[image]

For this problem the eigen values are $5$, $-1$, $-1$ and the minimal polynomial is $x^2-4x-5$.

From eigenvectors, I can see this as diagonalizable.

The question specifically asks to determine it from the minimal polynomial.
How do I determine it from the minimal polynomial?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833759/minimal-polynomial-of-diagonalizable-matrix

Answer (score 2):

The minimal polynomial  $x^2-4x-5=(x+1)(x-5) $ factors completely over $\mathbb R $ into distinct linear factors...  This is equivalent to diagonalizability [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)#Applications).