# Problem on characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

I am given two matrices a and b such that characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial of a and b are equal

I have to check

1. If they are similar
2. JC form of a and b are same
3. Rank(a) = rank(b)
4. If a is diagonalisable then b is also

My attempt:

I know a and are not similar for size of matrix greater than 3
So they do not have same JC form also

I also conclude that as they are not similar I can't be sure that if a is diagonalisable then b must be diagonalisable

How can I give argument for 3

Am I correct?

Comment: 4 is actually [true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833759/minimal-polynomial-of-diagonalizable-matrix)

Comment: What about 3 ??

Comment: A counterexample for 3 can be constructed for $4\times 4$ nilpotent matrices via Jordan forms in the spirit of 2: just pick the largest block to be $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and see how you can fill up the rest differently.