# Real matrix is diagonalizable on $\mathbb{R}$ if it is diagonalizable on $\mathbb{C}$ and all eigenvalues are real.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we are given a real matrix $A$. We know that we may regard it as a complex matrix (with real entries). Every complex matrix is similar to a Jordan form where all eigenvalues are placed on diagonal. Suppose the Jordan form $\Lambda$ of $A$ is real and diagonal. This implies $A$ is diagonalizable on $\mathbb{C}$: $PAP^{-1}=\Lambda$. The problem I 'm having is that $P$ may be complex so it does not directly imply $A$ is similar to diagonal $\Lambda$ even though $\Lambda$ is real--when we are now working with real instead of just complex field. If all diagonal entries on $\Lambda$ are distinct reals, this would imply diagonalizable over the real trivially. But what if there are eigenvalues with larger than 1 multiplicity?

Comment: Similarity of matrices never changes if you extend the field.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57242/similar-matrices-and-field-extensions

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is diagonalizable over the complex numbers and its eigenvalues are real, its minimal polynomial is $(X-c_1)...(X-c_p)$ where $c_1,...,c_p$ are the eigenvalues. Apply

[Prove that T is diagonalizable if and only if the minimal polynomial of T has no repeated roots.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2676557/prove-that-t-is-diagonalizable-if-and-only-if-the-minimal-polynomial-of-t-has-no)

Comment: This statement is not true in real.

Comment: look the proof in the accepted answer of the statement it does not use complex numbers.