# Linearly independent eigenvectors of $2 \times 2$ matrix with same eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $M$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ with characteristic polynomial $\chi =(x-\lambda)^2$ and minimal polynomial $m= (x-\lambda)^2$. My text claims that the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ is $1$.

I can only show this by "cheating":

$M$ diagonalizable (here) iff $\lambda$ has geometric multiplicity $2$ iff $m$ decomposes into **distinct** linear factors. Since $m$ does not decompose into distinct linear factors, we know that $\lambda$  can't have geometric multiplicity $2$.

Is there a way to show this without "cheating"? A more direct solution? Many thanks!

Comment: Why is that cheating? It's a valid argument.

Comment: Just seems like overkill (essentially referring to the primary decomposition theorem). I thought there might be a more direct and elementary way of showing this. In fact my text hinted at this: It considered some vector $v$ such that $(M-\lambda I) v \neq 0$. Then $(M-\lambda I)v$ must be an eigenvector of $M$ also with eigenvalue $\lambda$. From here my text just claims that this is the only independent eigenvector, but I can't see this ( unless I forget about the previous argument and "cheat").

Comment: Overkill yes, not cheating. If there were another independent vector $w$, then it and $(M-\lambda)v$ would span the whole space. So $M-\lambda = 0$, which is not the case.

Comment: @Chrystomath Thanks! That's what I was looking for!

Comment: @Cheesecake "If there is only one eigenvalue, then its eigenspace equals the whole of $V$"... How about the matrix with rows $(1,0)$ and $(0,0)$? Also this would mean that every $2  \times 2$ matrix is diagonalisable over $\mathbb{C}$, which is false. Since when is $(x−λ)^2$ not monic?

Comment: Sorry! I was thinking of the matrix \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}! Your first comment is incorrect.

Comment: This doesn't make alot of sense to me. $V$ is not necessarily the direct sum of eigenspaces. If it were, then every matrix would be diagonal. Your comments are incorrect. Anyway I'm out of here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that T is diagonalizable if and only if the minimal polynomial of T has no repeated roots.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2676557/prove-that-t-is-diagonalizable-if-and-only-if-the-minimal-polynomial-of-t-has-no)

Comment: My question was answered by @Chrystomath!