# Complex cyclic matrix is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

A matrix $A$ is cyclic if there exists an integer $m$, s.t. $A^m=I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Then it's said that every complex cyclic matrix is diagonalizable.

I know if a matrix has distinct eigen-vectors, then it's diagonalizable. And the minimal polynomial of $A$ should be $X^m-1$, which means it may have different eigen-values, so it may have distinct eigen-vectors. But I don't know whether it's right. Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: You are right, $x^m-1$ cannot have a multiple root since the derivation is $m\cdot x^{m-1}$ which can only have root $0$.

Comment: A matrix is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial [has not repeated factors](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/833759/81360).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, every matrix satisfying $X^m = I$ will be diagonalizable.  It suffices to note that a matrix is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial has no repeated factors [(see this post for instance)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/833759/81360).