# Find all possibilities for tr(A) and det(A) if $A^2=4I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix such that $A^2 = 4I$.

(a). Find all possible values of $tr(A)$ and $det(A)$.

(b). Show that $A$ is diagonalizable.

Note: As $A^2 = 4I$, it gives that $A$ is non-singular with $\lambda \in \lbrace\pm 2 \rbrace$. So, $tr(A) \in \lbrace -2n,-2n+2,\cdots,2n-2,2n\rbrace$ and $det(A)\in \lbrace -2^n,2^n \rbrace$. Is it true? I have no ideas for the second part.

Comment: Hint for (b) :minimal polynomial of A divides $x^2-4$ and the latter has simple roots!

Comment: @ChinnapparajR Thanks, but I don't want to use minimal polynomial.

Comment: Part (b) is false over any field of characteristic $2$.

Comment: note that $B:=\frac{1}{2}A$ is an involution, which is always diagonalizable over a field not of characteristic 2, since $\frac{1}{2}\big(B+I)$ is idempotent.

Comment: The field is complex numbers and not of characteristic 2.

Answer (score 0):

Over the complex numbers a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial is has roots of multiplicity 1 (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833759/minimal-polynomial-of-diagonalizable-matrix) for details).

In your case the minimal polynomial divides $x^2-4$ and so its roots are all of multiplicity 1.